# open-source PHP webapp for hierarchical chore todo list

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, todo

I want a web app that my son and I can use for tracking his chores.

Each chore should be extensible for adding corresponding columns for key=>value pairs, such as payment amount for completing chore, estimated difficulty/time of chore, due-date of chore, etc.

The chore data needs to allow for organization in a hierarchical structure such that sub-chores can have their corresponding column values roll-up into aggregate summaries. For example, a super-chore's payment amount for completion should be a dynamic sum of all its recursive sub-chores' payment amount for completion.

## Requirements

- webapp
- open source
- PHP-based
- hierarchical lists with aggregate attributes

## Preferences

- simple
- object oriented
- extensible list-item attributes
- draggable UI
- mixed database utilization. I'm envisioning a relational dbms like MySQL for back-end with a document dbms like MongoDB for front-end cache.

I am a PHP programmer, and I can write this from scratch, so I'm pretty loose on my requirements here. But since it's such a basic trivial project in general, I am sure there's at least 100 already available on Github if I could only find them - especially considering the to-do list on [Angular's home page](https://angularjs.org/), which seems to be a classic example app in any framework. I would like to find the best starting point I can, and then be able to fork the project and customize it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project management extention for WordPress called [WP-Project Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wedevs-project-manager/screenshots/)

Most of the time that would be spend to set it up would be cosmetic details to the front-end and the details for regular task management.

By setting it up on your local network using [XAMPP](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/) on Windows or MAMP on a Mac you would ensure security and eliminate the need for a domain and web hosting.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but after watching the video I see that it doesn't support hierarchical todo lists. I'm updating my question to clarify that need.

Comment: I'll keep my eye out. I know there have to be thousands of frameworks that meet your criteria. I will also be needing a similar tool soon so if you do manage to find something offline please update the post and I will do the same.